# distribute a number without remainder

Tags: php, arrays, division

I want to distribute an item to specific pieces without cutting the excess piece,
example:

```
$persons = 7;
$rooms = 2;

for($i = 0; $i < $rooms; $i++)
{
      //distribute the persons per room
}

//the endpoint should be
$the_room[0] = 4 //instead of 3.5
$the_room[1] = 3 //instead of 3.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an approach that first equally distributes pieces, then randomises the remainder?

```
$persons = 7;
$rooms = 2;
$the_room = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $rooms; $i++)
{
  $the_room[$i] = floor($persons / $rooms);
}

// Random Distribution
while( $persons - array_sum($the_room) > 0)
{
  $the_room[array_rand($the_room)]++;
}

// Sequential Distribution
// $index = 0;
// while( $persons - array_sum($the_room) > 0)
// {
//   $the_room[$index++]++;
// }

print_r($the_room);
```

Comment: Added a "Sequential Distribution" code block if you prefer to share the remainder in order.